# Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, mocking, react-navigation, react-test-renderer

```
it('renders correctly', async () => {
    const tree = renderer
        .create(
          <TTopBar
          tabBarScrollEnabled={true}
          containerHeight={350}
          initialRouteName={'Home'}
        screens={[
          {
            name: 'Home',
            component: HomeScreen,
          },
          {
            name: 'Settings',
            component: SettingsScreen,
          },
          {
            name: 'Profile',
            component: ProfileScreen,
          },
          {
            name: 'Tour',
            component: TourScreen,
          },
          {
            name: 'Fashion',
            component: FashionScreen,
          },
        ]}
      />,
    )
    .toJSON();
    await act(async () => {
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Throws this error
Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?
This can also happen if there are multiple copies of '@react-navigation' packages installed.

Mocking navigation introduces another set of error

Experts, please guide

Comment: What is the `TTopBar` component? Should this instead be a `NavigationContainer` component?

Comment: TTopBar is the component for which are I am writing unit test,

Comment: Even if i wrap TTopBar with NavigationContainer, I get the same error message

Comment: You should provide the code of the `TTopBar` component